# Route issue with subfolder in Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

we have decided to use subfolders in our Controllers folder. All our controllers are working like they should, but for one reason or another it doesn't get in the Controller method when we add an {id}

**Route:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Maintenance",
            url: "Maintenance/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TargetAudience", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "IstPhenix.Controllers.Maintenance" }
        );
```

This matches URLs like 
/Maintenance/Category/Index

but whenever we add the {id} like /Maintenance/Category/Edit/123456789 the Controller method cannot be found

**CategoryController.cs:**

```
[ClaimsAuthorize(PhenixPermissions = "ConsultCategory")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryId = id;

        return View("~/Views/Maintenance/Category/Edit.cshtml", id);
    }

    [ClaimsAuthorize(PhenixPermissions = "ConsultCategory")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Maintenance/Category/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

Usefull to mention is that we also have a default route at the end of our RouteConfig:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "IstPhenix.Controllers.Enduser", "IstPhenix.Controllers.Maintenance", "IstPhenix.Controllers.Security" }
        );
```

And then following URLs work when we omit the subfolder:

- /Category/Index
- /Category/Edit/123456789

Any idea why the URL does not match the route when i have a subfolder and an id?

What am i missing?

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

What if you added a `Route` attribute:

```
[Route("Maintenance/Category/Edit/{id}")]
[ClaimsAuthorize(PhenixPermissions = "ConsultCategory")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ViewBag.CategoryId = id;

    return View("~/Views/Maintenance/Category/Edit.cshtml", id);
}
```

That would explicitly give the route to the action.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but unfortunately i already tried that without success :(